# Mockito Correct Usage When stubbing a method with return value

Tags: mockito, spring-test

I have found following Test from the book **Mockito for Spring**:

```
import com.packt.trading.dto.Stock;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StockBrokerTest {
@Mock MarketWatcher marketWatcher;
@Mock Portfolio portfolio;
StockBroker broker;
@Before public void setUp() {
broker = new StockBroker(marketWatcher);
}
@Test
public void when_ten_percent_gain_then_the_stock_is_sold() {
//Portfolio's getAvgPrice is stubbed to return $10.00

when(portfolio.getAvgPrice(isA(Stock.class))).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("10.00"));

verify(portfolio.getAvgPrice(isA(Stock.class)))

//A stock object is created with current price $11.20

Stock aCorp = new Stock("A", "A Corp", new BigDecimal("11.20"));

//getQuote method is stubbed to return the stock

when(marketWatcher.getQuote(anyString())).thenReturn(aCorp);

//perform method is called, as the stock price increases by 12% the broker should sell the stocks

broker.perform(portfolio, aCorp);

//verifying that the broker sold the stocks

verify(portfolio).sell(aCorp,10);

}

public void perform(Portfolio portfolio,Stock stock) {
   Stock liveStock = market.getQuote(stock.getSymbol());
   BigDecimal avgPrice = portfolio.getAvgPrice(stock);
   BigDecimal priceGained =
   liveStock.getPrice().subtract(avgPrice);
   BigDecimal percentGain = priceGained.divide(avgPrice);
   if(percentGain.compareTo(LIMIT) > 0) {
     portfolio.sell(stock, 10);
   }else if(percentGain.compareTo(LIMIT) < 0){
     portfolio.buy(stock);
   }
}
```

I called

```
when(portfolio.getAvgPrice(isA(Stock.class))).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("10.00"));
```

but didn't verify using verify statement that getAvgPrice() is called or not. 
Also I didn't use the return value further in test case.

Should we only Stubbed those methods whose return value are evaluated or used further in test case?
Can't we write a when() without verify() or assertion of return value? Though, In both cases my Test run successfully.

Is it wrong usage of Mockito?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you unit test a method, remember:

> You are testing the method as a UNIT. When you provide all the required data to your UNIT(method), you have to `verify` / `assert` the **state** whether the outcome matches your expectations.

1. Here expectations mean that the proper behavior of a method as a unit.
2. The data to be provided would either be in input form or in the form of mocks or stubs from the dependent classes
3. Same goes with `exception` scenario as well. When you pass erroneous data, the expected outcome would be exception. You are testing the exceptional state.

Test cases would be successful as it did not encounter any abnormal behavior while execution. In general, `verify` or `assert` the **state** is what makes unit test meaningful

Comment: So if I write the verify statement like this : verify(portfolio.getAvgPrice(isA(Stock.class)))  Is it fine or do i need to assert the return value as well?

Comment: that completely depends on your use case. If the `perform()` is implemented to do any business logic by calling another method like `getAvgPrice(...)` then you may have to `verify` that method call. But I don't see any use doing `verify` on `getAvgPrice()`. If possible provide `perform()` implementation

Comment: verify(portfolio.getAvgPrice(isA(Stock.class))) statement and update() method added.

Comment: in your case you have to verify `portfolio.buy()` or `portfolio.sell()` call.